# initramfs every time booting into Windows on Dualboot with ubuntu 17.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, initramfs

I have run Dualboot Ubuntu with Windows for a long time and this started to happen with me since I installed any 17.04 xBuntu variation.

Every time I boot into Windows, the next time I try to boot into x/l/gnome/ubuntu, I got initramfs and only succeed if executed:

```
e2fsck -v -f -y -C 0 /dev/sdaX (ubuntu 17.04 installation partition)
```

The strange is that I have others linux installation, like Ubuntu 14.04 and Fedora 25, in other partitions and it only occurs on the 17.04 installation.

I am using EFI partition which shared boot efi partition for all installation.
It is very odd to me this and I don't know anymore what to do.

Comment: In Windows, have you installed a driver that allows you to read/write to Ubuntu EXT4 partitions?

Comment: Even if you're not using a Windows ext4 driver, you might want to check your partition type codes. See [this page of mine](http://nessus.rodsbooks.com/linux-fs-code/index.html) for details. Ubuntu 17.04 should have used the right type code from the start, but if you re-used an old Windows partition or set it up manually, it might have retained the wrong type code; or you might have accidentally set it incorrectly after installing.

Comment: @heynnema I am using ext2fs which mounts my linux partition under Windows. Is it causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got a Windows driver (like ext2fs) installed that allows you to mount/read/write to Ubuntu EXT4 partitions, then that's what is probably corrupting your Ubuntu installation. Uninstall this driver.

If you're looking to share files between Windows and Ubuntu, the best way is to create a new NTFS partition on your hard disk. Both Windows and Ubuntu can mount/read/write to this without causing problems.

Comment: I removed ext2fs and it worked right away